# How to sort keys in incomplete .json file (missing brackets) with Notepad++ or Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, notepad++

I have incomplete .json files, with missing brackets,
but always the same five keys: `"COUNTRY","CAPITOL","CURRENCY","POPULATION","OUTPUT"`

Those five keys are also always in random order, as you can see in this example:

```
      "COUNTRY" : "Japan",
      "CAPITOL" : "Tokyo",
      "CURRENCY" : "Yen",
      "POPULATION" : "126 500 000",
      "OUTPUT" : "4 971 000 000 000",

      "CURRENCY" : "USD",
      "CAPITOL" : "Washington, D.C.",
      "COUNTRY" : "USA",
      "OUTPUT" : "20 000 000 000 000",
      "POPULATION" : "328 000 000"
      ...
```

Therefore I cannot automate the process of adding brackets with (preferably) Notepad++, or with Python.

Any ideas how to do it?

I want the output always in the same order, like `"COUNTRY","CAPITOL","CURRENCY","POPULATION","OUTPUT"`.

Here's an example of the output I want to create:

```
      {"COUNTRY" : "Japan",
      "CAPITOL" : "Tokyo",
      "CURRENCY" : "Yen",
      "POPULATION" : "126 500 000",
      "OUTPUT" : "4 971 000 000 000"},

      {"COUNTRY" : "USA",
      "CAPITOL" : "Washington, D.C.",
      "CURRENCY" : "USD",
      "POPULATION" : "328 000 000",
      "OUTPUT" : "20 000 000 000 000"},
      ...
```

Any suggestions please? My idea is to sort the keys, but maybe there is another solution.

Comment: You would need to read the file in chunks of 5 lines (or more, depending on blank lines), parse each chunk into one dictionary, add it to a list, and finally output the list of dictionaries as JSON.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, if I can parse json in Python with doubled keys and without brackets. I'll try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Notepad++ with a weird regex!

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\G)\s*(?=[\s\S]*?("COUNTRY" : "[^"]+"),?\s?)(?=[\s\S]*?("CAPITOL" : "[^"]+"),?\s?)(?=[\s\S]*?("CURRENCY" : "[^"]+"),?\s?)(?=[\s\S]*?("POPULATION" : "[^"]+"),?\s?)(?=[\s\S]*?("OUTPUT" : "[^"]+"),?\s?)((?:.+\R?){5})`
- Replace with: `{\n$1,\n$2,\n$3,\n$4,\n$5\n},\n`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/AINWOd/1)

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]